# Skip email alert on same threshold value

Tags: bash

How do I add a function on the script below if the threshold value "MAX=85%" is the same as 85% the next time the script runs so I do not get repetitive emails. I only want to get an email if the above threshold level of MAX 85% goes beyond 85.

```
#!/bin/bash

DISK="/home" # disk to monitor
CURRENT=$(df -h | grep ${DISK} | awk {'print $4'}) # get disk usage from monitored disk
MAX="85%" # max 85% disk usage
MAX=""
DOMAIN="your.com"

# functions #
function max_exceeded() {

    # Max Exceeded now find the largest offender
    cd $DISK
    for i in `ls` ; do du -s $i ; done > /tmp/mail.1
    sort -gk 1 /tmp/mail.1 | tail -1 | awk -F " " '{print $2}' > /tmp/mail.offender
    OFFENDER=`cat /tmp/mail.offender`
    echo $OFFENDER
    du -sh $DISK/$OFFENDER > /tmp/mail.over85
    mail -s "$HOSTNAME $DISK Alert!" "$OFFENDER@$DOMAIN, admin@$DOMAIN"  < /tmp/mail.over85
}

function main() {
    # check if current disk usage is greater than or equal to max usage.
    if [ ${CURRENT} ]; then
            if [ ${CURRENT%?} -ge ${MAX%?} ]; then
            # if it is greater than or equal to max usage we call our max_exceeded function and send mail
            echo "Max usage (${MAX}) exceeded. The /home disk usage is it at ${CURRENT}. Sending email."
            max_exceeded
        fi
    fi
}


# init #
main

#CLEANUP
rm /tmp/mail.1
rm /tmp/mail.offender
#rm /tmp/mail.over85
```

Comment: Ever consider `awk '$0~/home/{sub(/%/,"",$5); print $5}' < <(df -h)` to get the current percentage for `home`?

Comment: I never try that. I will try but I just concern on the email alert

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag value in a temp file if an alert is triggered and check the next execution over that value.

If the alert is gone, unset the value / remove the file.

Comment: Or just write the last percentage go the temp-file and read the temp-file on startup and only report for percentages greater than the value in the temp file.

Comment: Hi Guys, Should I add a function base on the variables? I'm just a little confused how to apply the logic

Comment: In your case, you can use `/tmp/mail.offender` file, if it exists, send the alert.
Add another if condition in your main function to check for that file.

Comment: Do the cleanup part only when the alert is gone

Comment: Hey Lohit, Thanks for your help it works.!